# How to create dynamic page in wordpress and hide from menu

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin and i want to create a dynamic page when the user activates the plugin. Page creation is already done. But i want to hide it from the pages menu. No matter how wordpress is configured i want to hide the page.

Page can be only accessed using the url.

Can anyone provide me a solution for this.

Comment: Is the page you want to show to the user is in the admin panel? What do you mean by pages menu? Do you mean the admin menu of your plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by assign a different value to `post_type` like `dy_page`

for more info see: [Post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and [How to use Custom Post Types in WordPress 3.0](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-custom-post-types/)